# I am unable to get the forecast plot correctly

Tags: python, time-series, python-3.9, forecast

My dataset ranges from 2021-09-03 to 2022-06-04, and after splitting the dataset into train and test, when I use the forecast function, the plot starts from 1970. I am unable to figure out why.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPk8o.png)

Comment: From the plot forecasted value are around year 1970. That's the reason why it's starting from 1970. Need more information regarding question.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)